# DoctrinePHPcrBundle: Why use a separate connection if I also use ORM?

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-phpcr

In the [DoctrinePHPCRBundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/1.3/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm/introduction.html#phpcr-session-configuration) is stated:

> It is recommended to use a separate connection to a separate database
>   if you also use Doctrine ORM or direct DBAL access to data, rather
>   than mixing this data with the tables generated by Jackalope Doctrine
>   Dbal

Why?

Does this mean that if I'm using Doctrine to manage my entities I have to use a separate database to manage PHPCR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a best practice, not a requirement.

From a systems view of an application, this practice improves system availability and from an application view it improves a separation of concerns.